# Yocto mfloat-abi Configuration

Tags: gcc, opengl-es, yocto

I am getting following error, when I compile yocto project.

```
/home/yusuf/yocto/poky/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-ld.gold: error: /home/yusuf/yocto/poky/build/tmp/sysroots/bananapro/usr/lib/libGLESv2.so uses VFP register arguments, output does not
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:1082: recipe for target '../../lib/libQt5Gui.so.5.6.1' failed
make[2]: *** [../../lib/libQt5Gui.so.5.6.1] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/yusuf/yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/armv7a-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtbase/5.5.99+5.6.0-rc+gitAUTOINC+41706400f6-r0/build/src/gui'
Makefile:497: recipe for target 'sub-gui-make_first' failed
make[1]: *** [sub-gui-make_first] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/yusuf/yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/armv7a-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtbase/5.5.99+5.6.0-rc+gitAUTOINC+41706400f6-r0/build/src'
Makefile:45: recipe for target 'sub-src-make_first' failed
make: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
ERROR: oe_runmake failed
ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/yusuf/yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/armv7a-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtbase/5.5.99+5.6.0-rc+gitAUTOINC+41706400f6-r0/temp/log.do_compile.23834)
```

When I analyze libGLESv2.so libray with readelf command,I get following output

```
Attribute Section: aeabi
File Attributes
  Tag_CPU_name: "7-A"
  Tag_CPU_arch: v7
  Tag_CPU_arch_profile: Application
  Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
  Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-2
  Tag_FP_arch: VFPv3-D16
  Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t: 4
  Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
  Tag_ABI_align_needed: 8-byte
  Tag_ABI_enum_size: int
  Tag_ABI_HardFP_use: SP and DP
  Tag_ABI_VFP_args: VFP registers
  Tag_ABI_optimization_goals: Aggressive Speed
  Tag_CPU_unaligned_access: v6
  Tag_DIV_use: Not allowed
```

But when I analyze another library(libglib,libstd++,libncurses etc.) I get following output

```
Attribute Section: aeabi
File Attributes
  Tag_CPU_name: "7-A"
  Tag_CPU_arch: v7
  Tag_CPU_arch_profile: Application
  Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
  Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-2
  Tag_FP_arch: VFPv3
  Tag_Advanced_SIMD_arch: NEONv1
  Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t: 4
  Tag_ABI_FP_rounding: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
  Tag_ABI_align_needed: 8-byte
  Tag_ABI_align_preserved: 8-byte, except leaf SP
  Tag_ABI_enum_size: int
  Tag_CPU_unaligned_access: v6
```

As I understand, only the OpenGL libraries were compiled as hard float. All other libraries were compiled as soft float. So I am getting the error mentioned above.
What can I do about this problem? Why are only the OpenGL libraries compiled as hard float?

Comment: Which version/revision of poky are you using? Which `bitbake` command caused the error? Are you using any additional layers? Have you tried to run a `cleanall` and build it again?

Comment: I am using Yocto Jethro 2.0 version and yes I am usin meta-qt5,meta-oe,meta-ruby and meta-sunxi layer. I didn't tried to run cleanall.

Comment: Have you checked that the other layers are also on the same version (jethro)? Did a `cleanall` help?

Comment: Yes I checked.And I tried to cleanall but result is same

Comment: Can you check your machine conf file (for your target platform), what is the value of DEFAULTTUNE there?